# using snakemake.utils in profile without using conda-not-block-search-path-envvars

Tags: snakemake

I just updated from snakemake 5.28 to 5.32, and now `from snakemake.utils import read_job_properties` throws an import error for my job submission script in my snakemake profile:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ebio/abt3_projects/software/dev/ll_pipelines/llmgqc/bin/ll_pipeline_utils/profiles/sge/sge-submit.py", line 7, in <module>
    from snakemake.utils import read_job_properties
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snakemake'
```

Using `--conda-not-block-search-path-envvars` prevents this import error, but I'd rather not have to use `--conda-not-block-search-path-envvars` every time I run snakemake.

I don't see anything special that the [SLURM snakemake profile](https://github.com/Snakemake-Profiles/slurm/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.profile_name%7D%7D/slurm-submit.py) uses to get around this import issue, so I really don't know what to do besides using `--conda-not-block-search-path-envvars` all of the time.